# Salesforce - Edit field on before delete

Tags: apex, before-trigger, isdeleted

I need  modify a custom field (datetime) when the record is deleted

If I modify in before delete I get an error "There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help."

```
        for(Account acc: acc.oldList){
             acc.MyCustomDate = System.now();
        }
```

Is it possible to modify a field when the record is going to be deleted?

Comment: Not by using the read-only instances in `trigger.old` or `trigger.oldMap`, but I'm geting ahead of myself. Why are you looking to do this? What difference does it make (since the record is going to be deleted)? There's probably an issue elsewhere that needs solving without the help of a trigger (or at least not a delete trigger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the record via DML in a before delete trigger. Here's a copy-paste example:

```
trigger markAccountAsDeleted on Account (before delete) {
    Account[] accounts = new Account[0];
    for(Account record: Trigger.old) {
        accounts.add(new Account(Id=record.Id, Name='Deleted'));
    }
    update accounts;
}
```

Which works when tested with execute anonymous:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Demo');
insert a;
delete a;
a = [SELECT IsDeleted,Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.Id ALL ROWS];
System.assertEquals('Deleted', a.Name);
System.assert(a.IsDeleted);
```

Comment: Its works, thanks